# Can the Mega Stones at the Stone Emporium in Lumiose City be bought multiple times?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have seen info about how the stones' price will change with your style, but I haven't found anywhere if each can be bought more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this, I threw away a Charizardite X and talked to him again, and he didn't offer me another mega stone.

I don't know if it will be different if you trade it away, but I doubt it.

Comment: Addendum to this - I waited for 5 days since talking to him the first time, and he still didn't offer me another mega stone.

Answer (score 3):

After receiving all the Mega Stones from the vendor, he will not offer any more. However, I have not yet tested whether he will sell them again if you lose a Stone (e.g. through trading). So, until I can do that sort of testing, I have to say that you *cannot* purchase the Mega Stones multiple times.